# WebSQL as a html5 mobile offline answer via MySQL/PHP

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

updated... trying to add static data into WebSQL and I throw no errors but I have an empty table. Not sure what I am missing here.
Here is my static javascript code:

```
var db = openDatabase('semi33', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function(tx) {
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mtgs ( id INTEGER, dist INTEGER, sn INTEGER, name TEXT, loc TEXT, add TEXT, add2 TEXT, city TEXT, zip INTEGER, lat REAL, lng REAL, day INTEGER, time INTEGER, o INTEGER, c INTEGER, bb INTEGER, tw INTEGER, l INTEGER, s INTEGER, w INTEGER, m INTEGER, g INTEGER, b INTEGER, h INTEGER, n INTEGER, cc INTEGER, a INTEGER, addl TEXT, eda TEXT, eeda TEXT, etyp TEXT, etit TEXT, edesc TEXT, espkr TEXT, espkr_fr TEXT, edspy INTEGER, dsplyst INTEGER,  dsplyend INTEGER,  mes TEXT );")
});

db.transaction(function(tx) {
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO mtgs (id,dist,sn,name,loc,add,add2,city,zip,lat,lng,day,time,o,c,bb,tw,l,s,w,m,g,b,h,n,cc,a,addl,eda,eeda,etyp,etit,edesc,espkr,espkr_fr,edspy,dsplyst,dsplyend,mes) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",[1,12,637280, 'Southgate A.A. Study Group','Calvery Reformed Church','14151 Trenton Rd','NULL','Southgate',48195,42.205124,-83.192635,5,1830,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,'NULL',0,0,'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',0,0,0,'NULL'])
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe WebSQL was officially deprecated as a standard by W3C a couple of years ago which means that as a developer you are probably best to avoid it as the specification will no longer be updated and browser vendors are unlikely to continue to support their implementations.

I would suggest you look at [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/IndexedDB) which is the technology the W3C are pursuing for the storage of large amounts of structured data within the browser and which has [reasonable support](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/websql-indexeddb/) across the major modern browsers (no Safari though). There's a [WebSQL to IndexedDB migration guide](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/websql-indexeddb/) here which may be useful.

You might also want to consider [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) which allows you to persist key/value pairs within the browser and has the advantage of [near universal support](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage) in modern browsers.

Comment: Yeah its a shame for me the W3C decision on this matter, I am sure they have valid reasons. My target audience will be accessing this particular webpage using mobile browsers. I had considered IndexedDB, and don't totally rule it out, but it seems there is better mobile support in browsers for WebSQL than IndexedDB. I was considering maybe using json, or looking into if this would make sense.

Comment: Have you looked at localstorage (see updated answer)?

Comment: Wow it now looks like it is supported much better than the last time I looked. Thanks will dig in!

Comment: You'd be better off posting a new question - it will get much wider attention.

Comment: Thank you I am not real sure of site edict. I will create a new question, should I somehow close this one?

Comment: It's not so much an edict, but because this question has been answered it will receive less attention than a new question. What you should probably do is create a new question with the details above and restore the original question here from the edit history.